# How can i generate combinations randonly respecting rules?

Tags: javascript

How can i generate another (randonly) combination with the same apparitions?

for example in this case:

```
["L", "DR", "TK", "G5", "23", "LL"]
["TI", "CR", "PR", "H1", "TQ", "ISP"]
["K", "DR", "CO", "RG", "23", "PB"]
["GW", "L", "TK", "H1", "23", "CN"]
```

rule:

the first column is: 'L', 'TI', 'K' and 'GW'
the second column is: 'DR', 'CR', 'DR' and 'L'
the third column is: 'TK', 'PR', 'CO' and 'TK'
....

L only should appear 1 time on the first column

TI only should appear 1 time on the first column

K only should appear 1 time on the first column

GW only should appear 1 time on the first column

DR only should appear 2 times on the second column

CR only should appear 1 times on the second column

L only should appear 1 times on the second column

TK only should appear 2 times on the thrird column

PR only should appear 1 times on the thrird column

CO only should appear 1 times on the thrird column

i was trying, but with this code always i am getting the same combinations, i need more combinations ramdonly respeting the rules

```js
function* iterHeapsAlgo(arr) {

  const A = Array.from(arr); // shallow copy
  const len = A.length;
  const c = new Array(len).fill(0);
  let i = 0;
  yield A;
  while(i < len) {

    if(c[i] < i) {
      let j = i&1 ? c[i] : 0;
      if(A[i] != A[j]) {
        [A[j], A[i]] = [A[i], A[j]];
        yield A;
      }
      c[i]++;
      i = 0;
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      i++;
    }
  }
};

// Iterate over all combinations of all rows
// Typical counting algorithm with shortcut to take advantage of exposed state
function* iterCount(data) {
  const state = data.map(v => iterHeapsAlgo(v));
  const current = state.map(v => v.next().value);

  yield current;
  while(true) {
    const isEnd = state.every((v,i) => {
      let n = v.next();
      if(n.done) {
        state[i] = iterHeapsAlgo(data[i]);
        current[i] = state[i].next().value;
        return true;
      }
    });
    if(isEnd) return;
    yield current;
  }
}

const validate = data => {
  
  const set = new Set();
 
  const res= data[0].every((_,i) => {
    set.add(data.reduce((s,v) => s+v[i]));
    return set.size-1 == i;
  });
  return res
};

const solve = start => {
  const state = iterCount(start);
  while(true) {
    const current = state.next();
    
    if(current.done) break;
    if(validate(current.value)) {
      return current.value.map(v => Array.from(v)); // depth 2 copy
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(solve([
  ['1','1','1','2'],
  ['5','9','9','9'],
  ['7','4','6','4'],
]) || 'No solution found');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "should only appear 1" or "should only appear 2" ?

Comment: @danh the first column is: 'L', 'TI', 'K' and 'GW', then L only could appear 1 time

Comment: Are you able to provide a link for the original puzzle?

Comment: @Ouroborus its not a puzzle, sorry is for real life

Comment: @Ouroborus now i will use with few datas, not hundred or more

Comment: It would be pretty simple to adjust `solve` so that it produces all solutions. Is that what you needed?

Comment: @Ouroborus in each call it should return another combination or directly all combination is ok as well

Comment: @Ouroborus but if the input is an array of arrays with length = 4, the output as well should return with the same lenght

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem description. However, you provided code that seems to work for you and, based on the comments, you either want it to produce a random result on each call or you want a list of all answers.

---

If you want a random result on each call then, since the algorithm is deterministic, you'll need to somehow randomize the input. Here we randomize the array every time a sequence is refreshed. This causes the algorithm to search the solution space in random order:

```js
// Fisher-Yates shuffle
const shuffle = arr => {
  for(let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
};

function* iterHeapsAlgo(arr) {
  const A = Array.from(arr); // shallow copy
  shuffle(A);
  const len = A.length;
  const c = new Array(len).fill(0);
  let i = 0;
  yield A;
  while(i < len) {

    if(c[i] < i) {
      let j = i&1 ? c[i] : 0;
      if(A[i] != A[j]) {
        [A[j], A[i]] = [A[i], A[j]];
        yield A;
      }
      c[i]++;
      i = 0;
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      i++;
    }
  }
};

function* iterCount(data) {
  const state = data.map(v => iterHeapsAlgo(v));
  const current = state.map(v => v.next().value);

  yield current;
  while(true) {
    const isEnd = state.every((v,i) => {
      let n = v.next();
      if(n.done) {
        state[i] = iterHeapsAlgo(data[i]);
        current[i] = state[i].next().value;
        return true;
      }
    });
    if(isEnd) return;
    yield current;
  }
}

const validate = data => {
  
  const set = new Set();
 
  const res= data[0].every((_,i) => {
    set.add(data.reduce((s,v) => s+'\uffff'+v[i]));
    return set.size-1 == i;
  });
  return res
};

const solve = start => {
  for(const current of iterCount(start)) {
    if(validate(current)) {
      return current.map(v => Array.from(v)); // depth 2 copy
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(solve([
  ["L", "DR", "TK", "G5", "23", "LL"],
  ["TI", "CR", "PR", "H1", "TQ", "ISP"],
  ["K", "DR", "CO", "RG", "23", "PB"],
  ["GW", "L", "TK", "H1", "23", "CN"],
]) || 'No solution found');
```

---

If you want all possibilities, then change `solve()` so that it collects solutions rather than exiting after the first one.

I've commented out a `console.log()` and I've added a `limit` option. The browser locks up while this is running so logging doesn't appear until it's done and there are a *lot* of solutions.

```js
function* iterHeapsAlgo(arr) {
  const A = Array.from(arr); // shallow copy
  const len = A.length;
  const c = new Array(len).fill(0);
  let i = 0;
  yield A;
  while(i < len) {

    if(c[i] < i) {
      let j = i&1 ? c[i] : 0;
      if(A[i] != A[j]) {
        [A[j], A[i]] = [A[i], A[j]];
        yield A;
      }
      c[i]++;
      i = 0;
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      i++;
    }
  }
};

function* iterCount(data) {
  const state = data.map(v => iterHeapsAlgo(v));
  const current = state.map(v => v.next().value);

  yield current;
  while(true) {
    const isEnd = state.every((v,i) => {
      let n = v.next();
      if(n.done) {
        state[i] = iterHeapsAlgo(data[i]);
        current[i] = state[i].next().value;
        return true;
      }
    });
    if(isEnd) return;
    yield current;
  }
}

const validate = data => {
  
  const set = new Set();
 
  const res= data[0].every((_,i) => {
    set.add(data.reduce((s,v) => s+'\uffff'+v[i]));
    return set.size-1 == i;
  });
  return res
};

const solve = (start, limit = 1) => {
  const results = [];
  let i = 0;
  for(const current of iterCount(start)) {
    if(validate(current)) {
      results.push(current.map(v => Array.from(v))); // depth 2 copy
      // console.log(current);
      if(++i >= limit) break;
    }
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(solve([
  ["L", "DR", "TK", "G5", "23", "LL"],
  ["TI", "CR", "PR", "H1", "TQ", "ISP"],
  ["K", "DR", "CO", "RG", "23", "PB"],
  ["GW", "L", "TK", "H1", "23", "CN"],
], 5));
```

Comment: your are iterate by rows not by columns, i think is necessary use transpose?